# "Identifier is undefined" error after I explicitly defined the method

Tags: c++

I wrote the following code, composing of two classes, Item and Integer. Integer is derived from Item and has a value "data". I wrote a printAll method which is meant to print one by one the elements of an array containing pointers but when I try to implement the printAll method in the main function I am getting an error saying it is undefined even though I defined it using the print method in the Integer class above.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Item
{
public:
    // prints data
    virtual void print() = 0;

    // returns “INTEGER”
    virtual string getType() = 0;

    // Adds or concatenates the 2 data members. 
    // Throws an exception in case of a type mismacth 
    virtual Item* add(Item* item) = 0;
};

class Integer : public Item {
private:
    int data;

public:
    Integer(int i) {    //Constructor
        data = i;
    }

    void print() {
        cout << "Integer value is: " << data << endl;
    }

    string getType() {
        return "INTEGER";
    }

    Item* add(Item* item) {
        if (item->getType() == "INTEGER") {
            dynamic_cast<Integer*>(item)->data;
        }

        else {
            throw "Type Mismatch";
        }
    }

    void printAll(Item** items, int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            items[i]->print();
        }
    }
};

void main()
{
    int n = 10;
    Item** integers = new Item * [n];
    Item** strings = new Item * [n];

    // populate lists
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        integers[i] = new Integer(i);
    }

        printAll(integers, n);      // print integers
```

Comment: `printAll` is a member function `Integer`, but you are calling it as if it was a free function. Did you intend to make it a free function?

Comment: Please copy and paste the error message exactly as it appears in your compiler output. Also, don't you need to `#include <string>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mistake is that you put `printAll` in the `Integer` class. Change your code like this

```
class Integer : public Item {
    ...
};

void printAll(Item** items, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        items[i]->print();
    }
}
```

If a method is in a class, then you must (explicitly or implicitly) provide an object to call that method on. You didn't do that which is why you got the error. But in this case `printAll` should not be in any class, it should just be a regular function that you can call without supplying an object.